# Cannot resolve method reduce when using Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am follow the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#reducefunction) of Apache Flink to sink data, this is my code:

```
     consumeRecord.keyBy("gameType")
                    .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
                    .reduce(new MyReduceFunction(),new MyProcessWindowFunction());

 private static class MyReduceFunction implements ReduceFunction<ReportPump> {
        public ReportPump reduce(ReportPump d1, ReportPump d2) {
            d1.setRealPumpAmount(d1.getRealPumpAmount() + d2.getRealPumpAmount());
            d1.setPumpAmount(d1.getPumpAmount() + d2.getPumpAmount());
            return d1;
        }
    }

    private static class MyProcessWindowFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction<ReportPump, Tuple2<Long, ReportPump>, String, TimeWindow> {
        public void process(String key,
                            Context context,
                            Iterable<ReportPump> minReadings,
                            Collector<Tuple2<Long, ReportPump>> out) {
            ReportPump min = minReadings.iterator().next();
            out.collect(new Tuple2<Long, ReportPump>(context.window().getStart(), min));
        }
    }
```

but the code tell me:

```
Cannot resolve method 'reduce(com.sportswin.rdw.PumpRealtimeHandler.MyReduceFunction, com.sportswin.rdw.PumpRealtimeHandler.MyProcessWindowFunction)'
```

what should I do to fix this problem? The ReportPump is the entity I defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `.keyBy("fieldName")` Flink cannot deduce type of the key you are requesting. That's why it assumes generic type `Tuple` as a key type and your processing function should extend `ProcessWindowFunction<ReportPump, Tuple2<Long, ReportPump>, Tuple, TimeWindow>`.

If you instead want to keyBy `gameType` field within your data that has `String` type you can call something along the lines:

```
.keyBy(pump -> pump.getGameType() // I assume this has a String type
```

and then your code will compile.